# Search As You Type in C#

Tags: c#, search, types

I am using Search As You Type in C# as described here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138595/Search-As-You-Type-in-C

This works fine with one exception if the data in the underlying table
changes it never shows up in the datagrid unless I refresh everything I 
have done several searchs but can find a way to get the bindingsource 
to update

```
//This method is fired by the KeyUp event handler on the textbox.
//The purpose of this method is to take the text from the search
//box, split it up into words, and then create and assign a filter
//statement that will do a LIKE comparison on each of the selected
//search fields. Each word's filter statement is AND'ed together
private void txtSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string outputInfo = "";
    string[] keyWords = txtSearch.Text.Split(' ');

    foreach (string word in keyWords)
    {
        if (outputInfo.Length == 0)
        {
            outputInfo = "(Name LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR ProductModel LIKE '%" +
                word + "%' OR Description LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
        }
        else
        {
            outputInfo += " AND (Name LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR ProductModel LIKE '%" + 
                word + "%' OR Description LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
        }
    }

    //Applies the filter to the DataView
    myView.RowFilter = outputInfo;
}
```

Comment: Preaching the bad news of Sql Injection : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx . Don't directly incorporate user data in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

My experience here is limited but I ran into a similar problem on my own recently as well. If you're working with web forms (which I think you are if you're having this problem), since the data set is stored server-side, you can't force the client to refresh its display without an event calling an update method or the page reloading.

You can use some of ASP.net's built in AJAX tools to workaround this, like placing your DataView inside of an UpdatePanel and adding an update condition. (One sloppy but effective method is to just update on a timer)

Comment: This is a windows form not ASP I am very new to this I am using a binding source to fill the datagrid then as the sample code shoes a filter

Comment: Have you tried just calling dataBind() again after you change the underlying data?

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience but I am not sure of the syntax for dataBind()

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, thinking of web forms again, ignore that. When you say you can't get table changes to show up in the grid without 'refreshing everything', what do you mean by refresh if you're using Windows forms?

Comment: I populate my grid with  this.partsTableAdapter.FillBy4(this.pARTSDataSet.Parts); If someone else makes a change to the underlying table it does not show up in the grid (remember I am using filter to control what shows up in the grid) unless re rerun  this.partsTableAdapter.FillBy4(this.pARTSDataSet.Parts);